# QFontMetrics::horizontalAdvance() is wrong when the initial point size of the font is -1

Tags: qt, qt5, qfont, qfontmetrics

When constructing a `QFont` instance `f` with the default point size of -1 (doc says *the point size of the font is set to a system-dependent default value*), `QFontMetrics {f}.horizontalAdvance()` returns a value which is greater than what I expect.

Here's a complete demo:

```
class QTextWidthTest :
    public QWidget
{
public:
    QTextWidthTest()
    {
        this->setFixedSize(600, 400);
    }

private:
    void _paintExample(QPainter& painter, const int pointSize,
                       const QString& text) const
    {
        const QFont font {"sans-serif", pointSize};

        // draw text
        painter.setFont(font);
        painter.setPen(QColor {"black"});
        painter.drawText(0, 0, text);

        // draw horizontal advance
        painter.setPen(QPen {QColor {"red"}, 2});
        painter.drawLine(0, 3, QFontMetricsF {font}.horizontalAdvance(text), 3);
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override
    {
        QPainter painter {this};
        const auto sysPtSize = QApplication::font().pointSize();

        painter.translate(50, 50);
        this->_paintExample(painter, sysPtSize, "meow");
        painter.translate(0, 50);
        this->_paintExample(painter, sysPtSize, "hello world!");
        painter.translate(0, 50);
        this->_paintExample(painter, sysPtSize, "hello how are you today?");
        painter.translate(0, 100);
        this->_paintExample(painter, -1, "meow");
        painter.translate(0, 50);
        this->_paintExample(painter, -1, "hello world!");
        painter.translate(0, 50);
        this->_paintExample(painter, -1, "hello how are you today?");
    }
};
```

Here's the result:

[image: 1]

Is this a known behaviour or a known bug?

Comment: What if you use the [other QFontMetrics constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#QFontMetrics-2) that uses the paint device too? Have you tried other fonts?

Comment: @musicamante _If the paintdevice is `nullptr`, the metrics will be screen-compatible, ie. the metrics you get if you use the font for drawing text on a widgets or pixmaps_: that's my case. Yes I tried other fonts (`monospace` for example) and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that should be the expected behavior, but since many constructors go through lots of internal procedures (especially when dealing with delicate matters as DPI and font management), trying it anyway doesn't hurt. Further tests should be appropriate too: for instance, trying with a simple `QFont()` followed by `setFamily()`, which doesn't always get the same result as `QFont(family)` (a common case is `QFont('monospace')` against `font = QFont()` > `font.setFamily('monospace')`, which on many systems results in two *different* monospaced fonts).

Comment: Ok, I was finally able to test and reproduce the issue (while not exactly with so much difference in width). As stated above, the difference comes from using `QFont(family)` and `QFont()` + `setFamily()`. AFAIU, the former doesn't immediately resolve the family and only does that at some point (but fails to select the "correct one"), while `setFamily()` also sets the `FamiliesResolved` flag, *assuming* a family instead. My assumption is that, the resulting font families, while similar, may have different metrics, and the QFontMetrics constructor just assumes one (possibly the first?) as valid.

Comment: Hey @musicamante thanks a lot for the investigation! Is this a known (documented) behaviour/limitation, or should I file a bug? I find it kind of crazy that the two `QFont` setups may lead to different effective fonts.

Comment: It seems like a bug in the way the font metrics is actually created. From what I've seen `QFont(family)` sets a point size to 12 points if no point size is given (and it does it *always*, despite what the docs say), but in that specific case it doesn't flag the font as fully "resolved"; the inconsistent result then is that QPainter uses the default application font point size, while QFontMetrics uses the 12 point size. Explicitly calling `font->setPointSize(font->pointSize())` seems to fix the issue. I've found a partially related [QTBUG-6275](//bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-6275), but it »

Comment: » was never resolved and, most importantly, doesn't cover the inconsistency about drawing and font metrics. I'd suggest you to file a report including the code above. It will probably never be fixed for Qt5 but, at least, it might be for Qt6 - and a partial work around is available.